# AWS API Gateway authentication when making a call from browser extension

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

We have a requirement to send data to backend service using a browser extension. Extension is suppose to collect few data and then make a call to the API gateway endpoint with that data. I am puzzled by how we can provide authentication mechanism here

Extension doesn't enforce any sort of login, so can't think of a mechanism. And the extension can be on a public machine. Has anyone faced something similar in past. I am pretty sure that IAM based authentication is out of picture